# jquery hover to show menu issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a hover effect to show/hide a dropdown menu. The problem is when I hover over the link the menu shows but disappears again.

```
$(".hoverli").hover(
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
  }, 
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
  }
);
```

Please take a look at the demo here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/912/).

Can you tell me what I'm missing in the code?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(".hoverli").hover(function () {
      $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
  });
  $('ul.file_menu').bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium'); 
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/929/)

Answer (score 5):

The reason is, when you are on the `.file_menu` it is no more `hover`. So, a small change will fix.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").hover(
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
  }, 
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
  }
);

});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/915/

Comment: @kumo99 Wrap both the anchor and the `UL` on a common tag and give the hover on it. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the ul is not inside your anchor tag, so when you hover the ul, you're actually triggering the "out" event of the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tim;
    $(".hoverli, .file_menu").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearTimeout(tim);
            $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            tim = setTimeout(function() {
                $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/928/)

Comment: Moving over the link and menu makes it to `slideUp` and `slideDown`! :P